# Expressing a Lot with a Small Number of Operators

Tags: macros, common-lisp

In his book [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisptext.html), Paul Graham emphasizes that Lisp is “the extensible language”. He says this means building progressively higher language interfaces up toward a language in which an application can be usefully discussed or analyzed. This results in an orthogonal language ... in which you can express a lot by combining a small number of operators in a lot of different ways.  As an experiment I’d like to try and extend one of the more useful sequence functions, namely `remove`.

Putting aside for the time being extensions involving non-sequence data types (like removing elements from an array, hash table, or prop list), there is still room for extending the keyword selections. For example, there is no built-in provision for removing elements from a sequence based on their index. Along these lines, a programmer might want to remove elements whose value is the same as their index with a test something like `(lambda (elt idx) (= elt idx))`. The non-extensional approach would be to simply roll your own iterative function (one more among a hundred other hard-to-remember utilities), but it does seem more concise, reusable, and efficient to take advantage of the built-in functions and extend them.

The immediate problem is that `remove` applies only if there is a given search item, and `remove-if` requires a predicate that takes only one element as argument (not an element along with its index). The approach I would like to  explore attempts to merge the different options into one `remove-sequence` function, where the sequence is the only required argument, and everything else is keyword tailored to the specific kind of remove needed. Thus a search item is specified in an :item keyword, and the one or two argument boolean :test can include both an element and an index, as needed.  In this latter case a simple call might look like `(remove-sequence '(3 1 2 4) :test (lambda (elt idx) (= x i)))` removing the third element.

I've started with a function that seems to work on the following examples in SBCL:

```
(require :sb-introspect)

(defun remove-sequence (sequence &key item (test #'eql) from-end (start 0)
                         (end (length sequence)) (count (length sequence)) (key #'identity))
  (cond (item
           (remove item sequence :test test :from-end from-end
                                 :start start :end end :count count :key key))
        ((= (length (sb-introspect:function-lambda-list test)) 1)
           (remove-if test sequence :from-end from-end
                                    :start start :end end :count count :key key))
        ((= (length (sb-introspect:function-lambda-list test)) 2)
           (let* ((delta (if from-end -1 +1))
                  (initial-index (if from-end (length sequence) -1))
                  (closure (let ((index initial-index))
                             (lambda (element)
                               (setf index (+ index delta))
                               ;(print (list element index))
                               (funcall test element index)))))
             (remove-if closure sequence :from-end from-end
                                         :start start :end end :count count :key key)))
        (t (error "in remove-sequence macro"))))

(remove-sequence '(1 2 4 1 3 4 5) :test #'> :item 3) =>  (4 3 4 5)
(remove-sequence '(1 2 3 4 5 6) :test #'evenp :count 2 :from-end t) =>  (1 2 3 5)
(remove-sequence '(3 1 2 4) :test #'(lambda (elt idx) (= elt idx))) =>  (3 1 4)
```

However, I'm having trouble converting it into a macro, which so far looks like the following. (It generates an error during macro expansion.)

```
(defmacro remove-sequence (sequence &key item test from-end start end count key)
  (let ((tst (when test `(:test ,test)))
        (frm-nd (when from-end `(:from-end ,from-end)))
        (strt (when start `(:start ,start)))
        (nd (when end `(:end ,end)))
        (cnt (when count `(:count ,count)))
        (ky (when key `(:key ,key)))
        (test-fn (if test test #'eql)))
    (cond (`,item
             `(remove ,item ,sequence ,@tst ,@frm-nd ,@strt ,@nd ,@cnt ,@ky))
          ((= (length (sb-introspect:function-lambda-list test-fn)) 1)
             `(remove-if ,test-fn ,sequence ,@frm-nd ,@strt ,@nd ,@cnt ,@ky))
          ((= (length (sb-introspect:function-lambda-list test-fn)) 2)
             (let* ((delta (if `,from-end -1 +1))
                    (initial-index (if `,from-end (length `,sequence) -1))
                    (closure (let ((index initial-index))
                               (lambda (element)
                                 (setf index (+ index delta))
                                 ;(print (list element index))
                                 (funcall test-fn element index)))))
                `(remove-if ,closure ,sequence ,@frm-nd ,@strt ,@nd ,@cnt ,@ky)))
          (t (error "in remove-sequence macro")))))
```

Can this be fixed? Or is there a better way to write it? And more generally, is there a downside to tacking on maybe a dozen or so keywords? For example, I'd at least like to add boolean keywords for :duplicates and :destructive, and other keywords would probably be relevant for non-sequence arguments. Thank you for any experienced insights.

Comment: A part from the error, I think the example of Graham is more suitable for a function than for a macro. If you want to define a similar macro you should think about a syntax which is more expressive, and then convert such a macro in a call to the function.

Comment: Questions: What is the error? Why is it a macro? Do you know that a macro may run before the code is actually executed? Do you know that macros deal with source code, not runtime objects?

Comment: @Renzo, I may not understand your comment, but what I was trying to do with the macro is to substitute a macro call to `(remove-sequence ...)` with a corresponding call to a CL sequence function (ie, `remove` or `remove-if`) at compile time. This should make the runtime efficiency much greater than if `remove-sequence` were a function.

Comment: @Rainer Joswig, If I do `(macroexpand-1 '(remove-sequence '(3 1 2 4) :test #'(lambda (elt idx) (= elt idx))))` the error is "The value #'(LAMBDA (ELT IDX) (= ELT IDX)) is not of type FUNCTION when binding FUNCTION".

Comment: As I said: it's a list. Macros deal with source code, not with objects. It's not a function object. It's a list. You can't for example ask the test function for its arity in the macro -> the function does not exist yet.

Comment: It looks like I need a fn-designator-arg-count function that returns 1 for an input like `(function evenp)` or `(quote evenp)` or `(lambda (x) ...)` or `(function (lambda (x) ...)`, and >=2 for `(function >)` or `(lambda (x y) ...)`, etc, and error for anything else? Would something like `(coerce 'evenp 'function)` work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your function signature:

```
(sequence &key 
  item 
  (test #'eql) 
  from-end 
  (start 0)
  (end (length sequence)) 
  (count (length sequence))
  (key #'identity))
```

There is some good in providing a high-level interface to a lot of different operations, but then you have to be careful about performance too. Here above, you call `(length sequence)` twice every time you invoke your function. If the function was intended to be used with vectors only, that would be fine, but in the case of lists, you are doing two linear traversals. In terms of algorithmic complexity, that's not a problem given that remove is expected to be linear in time and space in the worst-case scenarios. But in terms of run times, there are a lot of cases where the worst cases do not arise but for which your implementation takes too much time.

In the standard `REMOVE` function, the default value for `:END` is nil, which has a special meaning here (the end of the sequence) without needing to actually compute the index. A function that processes a list can make use of that information without having to traverse the whole list; for example, here is roughly what should happen when count is 1:

```
(defun remove-first (item list)
  (if (endp list)
      nil
      (if (equalp (first list) item)
          (rest list)
          (cons (first list) 
                (remove-first item (rest list))))))
```

In practice, you could expect the code to not rely on tail-recursion elimination:

```
(defun remove-first (item list)
  (loop
     with stack = nil
     for (head . tail) on list
     do (if (equalp head item)
            (return
              (dolist (e stack tail)
                (push e tail)))
            (push head stack))))
```

You can even use infinite lists:

```
USER> (setf *print-circle* t)
T

USER> (remove-first 3 '#1=(1 2 3 4 5 6 . #1#))
(1 2 . #1=(4 5 6 1 2 3 . #1#))
```

So to conclude, one of the thing that is quite enjoyable in Common Lisp is that higher-level standard functions/abstractions have a predictable, non-surprising resource usage. Even though it is not specified as such, I expect that `map` in non-toy implementations will not cause stack overflows on large lists due to recursive calls, etc. It is good when libraries export functions and/or macros that follow the same approach. That could be a way to improve your existing code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments about the function. But its only purpose, as a template, was to help me write the macro. My objective with the macro was to see how much CL could be "extended" using macro expansion only into built-in CL functions, thus guaranteeing the same efficiency but with additional capability. I would be most interested in your comments about the macro if you have time (see working macro below).

Answer (score 0):

As Rainer Joswig comments above, the macro :test argument is a list understood as a function designator, not a function object. Transforming it into a function before passing it to sb-introspect:function-lambda-list should fix the error. Someone with more experience may be able to comment on whether `symbol-function` and `coerce` cover all possible cases:

```
(defmacro remove-sequence (sequence &key item (test '(function eql)) from-end start end count (key '(function identity)))
  (let ((tst (when test `(:test ,test)))
        (frm-nd (when from-end `(:from-end ,from-end)))
        (strt (when start `(:start ,start)))
        (nd (when end `(:end ,end)))
        (cnt (when count `(:count ,count)))
        (ky (when key `(:key ,key)))
        (test-fn (cond ((symbolp (second test)) (symbol-function (second test)))
                       ((eq (first test) 'lambda) (coerce test 'function))
                       ((eq (first test) 'function) (coerce (second test) 'function))
                       (t (error "Malformed :test function ~A" test))))
        (key-fn  (cond ((symbolp (second key)) (symbol-function (second key)))
                       ((eq (first key) 'lambda) (coerce key'function))
                       ((eq (first key) 'function) (coerce (second key) 'function))
                       (t (error "Malformed :key function ~A" key)))))
   (cond (`,item
            `(remove ,item ,sequence ,@tst ,@frm-nd ,@strt ,@nd ,@cnt ,@ky))
         ((= 1 (length (sb-introspect:function-lambda-list test-fn)))
            `(remove-if ,test ,sequence ,@frm-nd ,@strt ,@nd ,@cnt ,@ky))
         (t (let* ((delta (if `,from-end -1 +1))
                   (initial-index (if `,from-end (length `,sequence) -1))
                   (closure (let ((index initial-index))
                              (lambda (element)
                                (setf index (+ index delta))
                                ;(print (list element index))
                                (funcall test-fn (funcall key-fn element) index)))))
              `(remove-if ,closure ,sequence ,@frm-nd ,@strt ,@nd ,@cnt ,@ky))))))
```

Note there is still the problem of variable capture to deal with on the next draft.

Another issue involves the length of the arg list returned by sb-introspect:function-lambda-list. If the :test function has only one argument, then `remove-if` is the right expansion. If it has two or more arguments, then the expansion is either `remove` (if there is also an :item keyword), or `remove-if` with the closure (otherwise). There is no need to check for exactly two arguments. In fact, many acceptable :test functions have a lambda list longer than 2 (eg, #'>).

```
* (remove-sequence '(1 2 4 1 3 4 5) :test #'> :item 3)
 (4 3 4 5)
* (remove-sequence '(1 2 3 4 5 6) :test #'evenp :count 2 :from-end t)
 (1 2 3 5)
* (remove-sequence '(3 1 2 4) :test (lambda (elt idx) (= elt idx)))
 (3 4)
* (defun element=index (elt idx)
     (= elt idx)) ELEMENT=INDEX
* (remove-sequence '(3 1 2 4) :test 'element=index)
 (3 4)
*
```

Comment: You cannot determine in all cases, at macro-expansion time, if an expression refers to a function or not, even if you called `eval` on it. Consider expressions that, when evaluated, yield function objects, and in particular closures that depend on lexical scope. Consider simply `(remove-if (alexandria:of-type 'symbol) (list 1 :a 2))`. Your macro would be far more useful as a function. With the help of implementation-dependant facilities like SBCL `deftransform`, you could get the compiler to get what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44342104/124319

Comment: It sounds like you're implying macros may not be a fully viable stragegy for a user to build a more abstract language on top of lisp, somewhat contrary to what Graham suggests. (Although macros may have other uses.) Are there just too many macro subtleties for anyone but experts? I guess functions would work, but the performance penalty seems prohibitive (unless you went with something like `deftransform`).

Comment: I did not intend to imply that; from your macro you do not have access to runtime values, so there are almost always corner cases where you macro cannot know what type of data is going to be associated with the term you are manipulating, even if you have a static analyzer (which is what deftransform relies on). What I am saying is that the performance penaltly can be avoided by the macro in easy cases (literal lambdas, etc), and are unavoidable for certain inputs. A way to improve your macro would be to expand into code that performs introspection at runtime for unknown cases.

Comment: Great clarification. Coming to understand lisp's potential is exciting, but challenging!