# Passing let string values to macro - not a string?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, sbcl

I do not full understand how macros accept arguments.

In the following code:

```lisp
(macroexpand-1 
     (let ((des "des"))
       '(defhomepage 
         (:title "hi"
          :description des
          :canonical "can" ))))
```

my desired result is that the value "des" is passed directly to `defhomepage`.

Inside `defhomepage` I have a type checker:

```lisp
(defmacro defhomepage ((&key :title :description :canonical))
    (check-type description string)
    ...
    ...
)
```

I get an error that `des` is not of type string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

```
(defmacro defhomepage ((&key :title
                             :description
                             :canonical))
  (check-type description string)
    ...
    ...
 )
```

You are checking the type at macro expansion time.

**Remember a macro sees source code.**

For example a macro is expanded during compilation, before the code actually runs. The expanded code then runs at runtime.

If you have the form `(defhomepage ... :description desc ...)`, then the value of the local variable `description` is the symbol `desc` - which is the source code.

Also:

if you do

```
(macroexpand-1
  (let ((desc "foo"))
    '(defhomepage ... :description desc ...)))
```

then it would not work as you think. The form is expanded outside of the `let` and it can't see the binding anyway...

**Your question title**

*Passing let string values to macro - not a string?*

You were not passing a value to a macro. The macro sees the symbol `des`. During macroexpansion it's just a symbol, there is no lexical value associated to it.

Comment: I belive my misunderstanding is around `let`. Ive always seen let as "passing the value around". Is that inaccurate?

Comment: @Vinn : `LET` introduces a lexical variable `DESC`. In your code example with the `LET` there is no reference to it. So in your code example it is simply defining an unused variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defmacro defhomepage ((&key :title :description :canonical))
    (check-type description string)
    ...
    ...
)
```

Don't use keywords as variable names like `:title` (you are not allowed to rebind symbols in the KEYWORD package), prefer `title` instead (and this implicitly build a keyword `:title` for you). If you want to specify both the keyword and the function variable, use a pair instead:

```
(defun xyz (&key ((:my-key k)))
  ;; here k is bound to the value passed using :my-key keyword argument
)
```

There are two pairs of parentheses because a keyword is either:

- a single `symbol`
- a list `(var default)` or `(var default varp)`, where `default` is the default value and `varp` indicates if the argument was given explicitly by the caller. Here, `var` is either :

  - a single `symbol`
  - a pair `(keyword symbol)` where `keyword` denotes the keyword to use and `symbol` the local variable name.

Macros are a way to transform source code, your macro will be invoked as follows:

```
(defhomepage :title some-var)
```

The above is first read as a list of 3 elements, all symbols. There is no way to know at macroexpansion time which value `some-var` will later be bound when the code is executed (remember, `check-type` is dynamic type checking).

See [Using deftransform/defknown in SBCL internals to get the compiler to transform user authored functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44342104/124319) for ways to rely on declared or inferred static types for code rewriting.

The simplest solution however is to defer the call to `check-type` to execution. Your macro can return a form that looks like:

```
;; bad example
`(progn
   (check-type ,description string)
   ....)
```

Here you inject the actual argument given to your macro in `check-type`, but this can fail if for example you give an expression `(format nil "doc string ~a" foo)`, since `check-type` operates on *place* (something that can be `setf`). So you need to bind the argument to a local variable:

```
(let ((some-var (gensym)))
  `(let ((,some-var ,description))
     (check-type ,some-var string)
     ...))
```

Here above, `some-var` is a fresh symbol name, which in the resulting code is used to bind `description` to a local variable. That variable is a place and can be given to `check-type`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about macros.  Let's first look at your `macroexpand-1` call.

This looks like `(macroexpand-1 (let (...) ...))`.  Well, `macroexpand-1` is a function, so its argument will be evaluated.  The argument is, in more detail, `(let ((des "des")) (quote ...))`.  Well, what `let` does is bind some variables (here `des`) and then evaluate the forms in its body with those bindings in place, returning the value or values of the last one.  There is one form, and it is `(quote ...)`: it's a literal (a literal list, in fact).  So we don't have to worry about the binding, we can just return the literal.  So the whole form is now equivalent to `(macroexpand-1 (quote ...))`.

I can't work out the rest of your confusion fully, but I think the key insight you may be missing is that macros are *transformers of source code*: their arguments are fragments of source code, and their value is another fragment of source code.

In particular if a macro wants to be fussy about the types of its arguments then that fussiness should be what those types represent *as source code*.  Thus if I was writing a version of `let` as a macro the sort of fussiness I would be insisting on would be

- the first argument must be a list;
- each element of that list should either be a symbol, or a one- or two-element list whose first element was a symbol.

Because that is the *source code syntax* that `let` supports.

If a macro wants *the source code that is its value* to be fussy about types later, it should create code which performs those checks, at run-time, *not* macroexpansion-time.

Consider some simplified version of your macro

```
(defmacro deffoo (&key description ...)
  ...)
```

Well, `description` is just going to be some form in the body of the macro.  For instance I could use it as

```
(deffoo :description (concatenate 'string ... ...) ...)
```

And then in the body of the macro, `description` is `(concatenate 'string ... ...)`: a fragment of source code.

Well, it makes no sense to check that this is a string, because it is not.  Instead I want to check, *at run time* that its value is a string.  So I must return a fragment of source code which does that.  Here is a first, broken, attempt to do that:

```
(defmacro deffoo (&key description ...)
  `(progn
     (check-type ,description string)
     ... use description in other code ...))
```

**This is broken.**  It's broken because it will evaluate the form corresponding to `description` more than once and that is unsafe, since the macro can have no idea what that form is.  To resolve this it must do two things:

1. create code which, at run time, binds a variable to the value of the form;
2. ensure that that variable has an unspeakable name, so that none of the other source code fragments passed as arguments can refer to it by mistake.

Here is what that looks like:

```
(defmacro deffoo (&key description ...)
  (let ((descn (make-symbol "DESCRIPTION")))
    `(let ((,descn ,description))
       (check-type ,descn string)
       ... more code that uses descn ...)))
```

This is now both safe and performs the check at run-time.

Note that there is another style of macro, of which I suppose `let` would be the canonical example if it was a macro in CL, where the user of the macro gets to specify a variable name.  Perhaps a good example of this that is a macro is `with-open-file`.

But the important thing in all this is to remember that **macros operate on source code**: macros are functions whose domain and range is source code.

Finally, in your question you have syntax like `(&key :keyword ...)`: that's not legal.  The specification for keyword parameters is [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_dad.htm), and in particular if it is just a symbol it must *not* be a keyword symbol, since keyword symbols are [always constants whose value is themselves](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_abca.htm) and thus may not be bound to any other value.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a quote: this doesn't evaluate the form given to it. It returns it as is, a list of symbols:

```lisp
(let ((des "des"))
  '(foo des))
;; same as (quote …)
;; (FOO DES)
```

When you want the value of a variable, use a comma, and a backquote instead of a quote.

```lisp
(let ((des "des"))
  `(foo ,des))
(FOO "des")
```

But this mechanism doesn't replace constructors and function calls. Don't use macros unless you have to ;)